# Angular 2 routing - middle module is bypassed when lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am facing a problem when using Angular 2 routing, lazy-loading and forRoot().

The application is set up as follows:

- app.module.ts loads the PagesModule (no lazy-loading)
- app.routing.ts has the following routes:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'pages/users', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

- pages.module.ts import UsersModule.forRoot() "only"
- pages.routing.ts has the following routes:

```
    path: 'pages',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'users', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule' },
      { path: 'project', loadChildren: './projects/projects.module#ProjectsModule' }
    ]
```

- PagesComponent contains some html and a 'router-outlet'
- users.module.routing has the following:

```
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
```

The problem now is that, when I load the application, there are no redirects happening, it is always served from the '/' root and only the UserModule's component MainComponent is served without showing all the HTML in the PagesModule's PagesComponent template.

This behavior started when I added the UsersModule.forRoot() as I need to share a service at the Pages's module level as a singleton.

Any idea what could cause this 'bypass' for the PagesComponent template?

==UPDATE==
The below is a list of all routes in the app.

app.routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages/users', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

pages.routing: This module loaded when app starts.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'users', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule' },
      { path: 'project', loadChildren: './projects/projects.module#ProjectsModule' }
    ]
  }
];
```

users.routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: a while back I had issues when adding routing to submodules, so you could try putting everything into app.routing.ts while you are trying to find the source of the problem

Comment: can you list all your routes for better understanding of the routing

Comment: @RahulSingh I did, thank you